# How to obtain a direct way to differentiate between a full refresh and an incremental update for Delta live table?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake, delta-live-tables

I have a tables that travels from Bronze - silver - gold,

I want to implement some function like 'is_full_refresh()' so the pipeline filters the df depending on the output, if it's a full, don't filter, if it's incremental filter by a,b,c

Checking the documentation on Databricks https://docs.databricks.com/delta-live-tables/settings.html#cluster-config can't find a direct way to differentiate between a full refresh and an incremental,

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to rely on REST API call https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/pipelines/getupdate.

Another option I would try (requires some investigation) is to query DLT event logs: https://docs.databricks.com/delta-live-tables/observability.html. I guess some log events may have this info.

Comment: To add to the answer, /api/2.0/pipelines/{pipeline_id}/updates have the response "full_refresh": true which is exactly what I was looking for